RansomWare Defeated
So i Encrypted My C Drive Using DiskCryptor _ Big Mistake _ Let the Hackers Right in there & Wouldnt Boot After [ Stuck in Repair Mode ] the RansomWare Feature Comes in With the Fact that the Factory Reset Was Disabled By Default AND the System Restore through Asus Was [ Deliberately ] ineffective _ So i Command Prompted A Disk Clean Of My C Drive And Yet Again Am Facing RansomWare technology [ told i MUST Use A USB Stick ] i Refuse 2 Yield _ What Are My Options 4 Running Command From BIOS With No Functional OS ?

Replace your system board and your hard drives.  You have no options in this case.  Additionally, your quesiton is offtopic because it's about Windows (Drive C and DiskCryptor are Windows things) and this isn't a Windows forum

So Why Did You Answer _ Smart Guy ? You Sound Like A RansomWare Proponent 2 Me .

Fun fact: I have over 10 years in the cyber-security industry, saying I'm a ransomware proponent is a bad move, because fun fact Ransomware that infects your system firmware on the system motherboard for automated reinstall and encrypting has no other repair/fix solution. REGARDLESS, you need to find a Windows support forum, not an Ubuntu support forum, to get assistance with your issue. Windows is offtopic on this forum, plain and simple.
